# Using jshint with AngularJS and Controllers

Tags: angularjs, jshint

I am trying to incorporate JSHint into my build process. The app that I'm building uses AngularJS. Currently, I have a conflict that I'm not sure how to resolve. When I build my app, I get a JSHint error that says:

```
   src\app\app.js
      3 |var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
             ^ Redefinition of 'myApp'.

>> 1 error in 2 files
Warning: Task "jshint:source" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

I get this error because in my .jshintrc file, I have the following:

"predef": ["angular", "myApp"],

If I remove "myApp", I get a different error that says:

```
src\app\account\welcome.html.js
   3 |myApp.controller('WelcomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      ^ 'myApp' is not defined.

1 error in 2 files
```

The reason I am defining a controller like that is because according to the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller), you should not define controllers in the global scope. As you can see, its like I'm damned if I do, and damned if I don't. How do I follow the AngularJS best recommendations while still including JSHint in my build process?

Thank you!

Comment: Just ignore the `app` variable to jshint.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can fix this with a globals key in the .jshintrc file

```
{
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
    "esnext": true,
    "bitwise": true,
    "camelcase": true,
    "curly": true,
    "eqeqeq": true,
    "immed": true,
    "indent": 4,
    "latedef": true,
    "newcap": true,
    "noarg": true,
    "quotmark": "single",
    "undef": true,
    "unused": true,
    "strict": true,
    "trailing": true,
    "smarttabs": true,
    "multistr": true,
    "globals": {
        "myApp": false
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a difference in the globals value of true/false? I don't notice anything

Comment: @Ronnie the difference is whether you allow it to be reassigned. (false means "read-only")

Answer (score 3):

Why define a `myApp` variable at all? I define my app, controller, etc. this way. You can chain multiple controllers, factories, etc.:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])

.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.person = {
        nfname: 'John',
        lname: 'Deighan',
        email: 'john.deighan@gmail.com',
    };
});
```

Comment: The empty array argument at the end isn't needed. You can just do `angular.module('myApp')`.

Comment: @Splaktar, `angular.module('myApp')` fetches an existing module by that name, `angular.module('myApp',[])` redefines the `myApp` module with an empty list of dependencies. This is an important distinction, and a common cause of accidentally redefined modules.

Comment: Right. This example looks like it will lead to a lot of redefining of modules. Perhaps it could be expanded to include both cases for clarity.

Comment: The usage in the answer is fine as long as you repeat `.controller(...)` etc but never repeat the `angular.module` line itself.  You can chain any number of controller/directive/factory/whatever calls onto a single module call.

Answer (score 3):

The last given example is good, but as said if you call .module() with an empty array as a second argument you will redifine your module dependencies.
To avoid that, only pass the module name to .module()

```
angular.module('myApp')

.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.person = {
        nfname: 'John',
        lname: 'Deighan',
        email: 'john.deighan@gmail.com',
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

### Reasons:

#### Why redefinition?

Because you set `myApp` as predef in the `.jshintrc` file, jshint thinks `myApp` is already be defined in all the files in this project directory. So when you define `myApp`, error redefinition.

#### Why undefined?

Because there're not `myApp`'s definition in the **same** file. I guess you define it in `app.js` file. As you noticed, in the Angularjs documentation, their controller is all defined after the `myApp`, they are in the **same** file.

### Solution:

Don't need set `myApp` as predef or global in `.jshint`, I recommend that when you defined a controller or config, do it like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myController',
```